# SFTP and Yubikey

Tags: files, ftp, yubikey

I want to access my sftp server using a private key stored on a Yubikey 5. How do I do it? The internal file browser requires me to provide a local file with the private key. My system: Android 10, Samsung A71 (NFC support).

Comment: According to the Yubikey documentation some keys support the OpenPGP interface and in ssh OpenPGP can be used as private key source. On Linux and Windows collaboration between those standard programs is easy but on Android neither ssh nor OpenPGP is available directly and collaboration between apps does not work the same way as on Linux. Therefore the used sftp app has to support everything including the Yubikey support. Also the Yubikey documentation does not mention Android for ssh authentication which can mean that this platform is not supported at all in this scenario.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot, I was afraid of that.